# Node.js modules pushed to GitHub

Tags: git, github, gitignore, node-modules

I am trying to push my project to GitHub and Heroku. Since I am using Node.js in my app, I have folder *node_modules*. Before I commit I have created a file called `.gitignore` to ignore the Node.js modules.

Inside the file I have added folder *node_modules* and tried to push to the GitHub repository from the comandline/Terminal. I was not expecting the Node.js modules to be pushed, but they appeared finally in the repository. Is there an ways I have to follow?

### Here is how I resolve my issue

```
 - $ git rm -r --cached node_modules
```

Add folder *node_modules/* to your *.gitignore* file:

```
 - $ git commit -m "remove the ignored directory node_modules"
```

And then

```
 - $ git push origin master
```

After that, if you refresh the GitHub page you will see the *node_modules* folder gone.

Comment: Please provide your .gitignore file

Comment: Files that git already track won't be ignored by `.gitignore`, that file only provides rules for `git add`. If you've already added them, you need different tools to get rid of them.

Comment: `.gitignore` was already have `node_modules` to be ignored but for some reason when I pushed my code the `node_modules` pushed together with the other code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `node_modules` folder should be added to the `.gitignore` file.

First, get rid of your `node_modules`:

```
$ git rm -r --cached node_modules  
$ git commit -m "remove node_modules"
```

Then, push your change

```
$ git push origin master
```

Refresh the page to see the desired effect.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to add *node_modules* to your `.gitignore` file.

Then

```
$ git rm -r -chached node_modules
$ git commit -m "remove node_modules"
```

And then:

```
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: Re *"add node_modules to your .gitignore file."*: How exactly? Somebody else may want to chime in.

Comment: Add the line "node_modules" (no quotes) in your .gitignore file

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell Git to untrack the files that have been already added to Git (before you ignored them):

```
git rm --cached FILE
```

FILE won't be deleted from your filesystem. Git will untrack this fille, and since it's ignored, it won't be tracked anymore.

Then, of course you have to commit and push this change.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, is the `.gitignore` file inside the `node_modules` or in the root of the project?

If so, I'll recommend to place it (at least) in a parent folder, or ideally in the project's root, and inside it call `node_modules` as a relative path to the location of the file. i.e: `some-path/node_modules`.

Besides that, once the folder is committed and pushed, you should ignore the *.gitignore* file (by deleting it temporarily or deleting the node_modules line), so Git can keep track of the files, delete the folder, commit, push, and restore the *.gitignore* file.

Comment: What does *"If so"* refer to? The former or the latter? Can you make it more clear? Please respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44169878/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar).