# Heroku fails in deploying node.js with bcrypt

Tags: node.js, heroku, bcrypt, bookshelf.js

after adding bookshelf-secure-password to my server heroku has been failing in deploying my server it keeps saying it can't install bcrypt.

```
NPM_CONFIG_DISTURL=https://nodejs.org/download/release/
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  12.14.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   6.13.4
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 12.14.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.14.0...
remote:        npm 6.13.4 already installed with node
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:
remote:        > bcrypt@3.0.8 install /tmp/build_a26ccc13212d9e4abd4c4c76594f5696/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.8 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.8 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.aPY9Y/_logs/2020-03-01T18_03_19_337Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:          https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
```

I have tried to follow the heroku Troubleshooting Node.js Deploys site https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys but it didn't help, I have tried to install bcrypt, uninstall it and install bcryptjs but that doesn't help, I don't know what to do now, can anyone help?

Comment: Don't push your node_modules, let Heroku install them in the dyno for you.

Comment: I have added node_modules to the .gitignore file but it doesn't help

Comment: Have you actually removed it from the commit you're pushing, though? Otherwise you're only ignoring future changes to it.

Comment: okay how do I do that?

Comment: Did you read up on it? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168609/node-modules-pushed-to-github

Answer (score 0):

Even though node_modules shouldn't be pushed as mentioned in the comments, it seems that the problem is with node-gyp, not with node_modules itself.
I suggested switching from **bcrypt** package to **bcryptjs**. It is written in js and its performance is a bit worse, but it doesn't require python dependencies, which makes the build process less complicated. API is identical, so it would be trivial to change it in your code. It's not exactly an answer to your question, but I hope you find it helpful.

I would comment that instead of posting an answer, but my reputation is't high enough to do that.

Comment: You've mentioned trying using bcryptjs, but maybe node_modules that you pushed to the repository still had the bcrypt package inside and it somehow affected the build process even though it wasn't specified in package.json.

Comment: I did try that, as mentioned in the end of my post and it didn't work, but removing the node_ modules worked